# PHP Force downloding shows network error

Tags: php, force-download

I trying to make document download using PHP force downloading and i used the below code

```
 header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");

 header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path) ."\"");

 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($path)."\"");

 header("Expires: 0");

 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

 header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
 ob_clean();
 flush();

 readfile($path);

 exit;
```

But when i run the script it just shows download starting... and shows "Network error" in chrome and when i checked network console it shows something like this

```
Request URL:http://websddress.com/presse/index.php?option=com_presse&task=viewDoc&id=2578&lg=FR
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=139058359.696419680.1380560986.1380711878.1380731571.5; __utmz=139058359.1380560986.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); 58a32855c678fbf6131983dab57747c9=uv0bipblgn8bd3diqbd52dn9g1; 64cf32705845a188b511407ba5bcd3d6=edbgk8jtalamqnininr89qb327
Host:5.135.115.74
Referer:http:webaddress.com/presse/index.php?option=com_presse&task=viewDocs&secid=787&lg=fr
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
option:com_presse
task:viewDoc
id:2578
lg:FR
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Advanced_Fair_-_Grohe_september_doc_FR_2578.pdf"
Content-Length:"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:Binary
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Thu, 21 Nov 2013 15:49:29 GMT
Expires:0
P3P:CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path) ."\"");
```

outputs in headers this:

```
Content-Length:"
```

replace by:

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));
```

and fix the `$path` which is also not correct because it returns `null` (or `false`).

The output should be something like:

```
Content-Length: 10032219
```

Also, the correct mime-type for PDF is:

```
 Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Comment: Thanks.. it downloaded the files but it cant open. could you help me again..?

Comment: @ DanFromGermany Thanks alot. the path wasn't right. i solve the issue thanks again

Comment: There are many document types like jpg,png,docx etc That's why i used the Content-Type: application/octet-stream. And now i can't download only pdf files but not other formats even still i am using the content type application/octet-stream

Comment: @MufeedKKasim have a look at [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) which detects the mime-type of files so you can automatically always have to correct one!

Comment: `header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));`  - this saved my day tvm

Answer (score 4):

you should remove

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

There is no reason to flush the output before reading & sending the file. esp the flush() command might be causing the error / remove any spaces or new lines before the `<?php` tag

Comment: Yess i removed the ob_flesh(); clean(); but it still not open images and .docx files.It downloads as full size. I opened in notepad++ there are no PHP errors. But can't open files. And the strange thing is can download .pdf files